# Did discord change the "bulkDelete" variable in java script?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bulk-delete

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: 'clear certain amount of messages',
    async execute(message, args){

        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("please enter the amount of messages");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("please type a number");
        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("you can not delete more than 100 messages at a time.")
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("Number has to be more than 1")

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(message =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });
    }
}
```

Every time I run it, an error occurs:

> Cannot read property 'bulkDelete' of undefined

i have no idea what i did wrong. I checked the code in the video as well as went on discord.js.org to see if they had a different solution. If anyone can help, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`messages.fetch` resolves to a
[*`Collection`*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of messages. You need to pass that array to the `bulkDelete` method on the *original* message.

Also, since you're using `await`, you might as well remove the `.then`s entirely.

```
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]});
await message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```

But it would be easier to just pass the *number* of messages to delete.

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
```

I'd also recommend putting the `args[0]` into a variable beforehand, for better readability.

```
async execute(message, args){
  const numToDelete = args[0];
  // continue using numToDelete, not args[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You named the argument in the `.then()` function `message`, so it overwrote the first message object. You should rename it to `messages` because you reference that name on the same line.

A few tips:

- `args[0]` will be a string, not a number, so it won't take any effect. You can use the unary operator to convert it.
- There's no point fetching the messages, because you can just input a number to the `bulkDelete()` function

```js
await message.channel.bulkDelete(+args[0]);
```